# Report Builder cannot connect after successful connection test

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2017, reportbuilder

I have never faced such a problem. On the remote server outside our domain was created a new SSRS server. Everything seems to working fine, I could connect to **ReportServer** via https also to **Reports**.

Then I opened my Report Builder write connection there and it was also properly connected.
But after I tried creating new **Data Source** the problem begins.
In build connection function its all OK.

[image]

After that in **Data Source Properties** when I tried to test connection it gives me this error.
[image]

OKay I still decided to try create something in Dataset with simple query and it connect to SQL server to specified database and also I can see a fields in field list !
[image]
[image]

But after all that hope I'm still unable to run any report here. So can anyone please help me or guide me to any solution ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, turns out the datasource needs to connect to the IP of the server, and not the hostname. The user who connected via VPN did not have a notion of the hostname because no DNS is provided over the VPN. By changing the hostname in the connection string to the IP of the server it was possible to use the query editor in the report builder over the VPN connection.

[image: Example of datasource properties]